# How to make <a> wrap around a small image with out padding?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<a href="#" style="border:solid 1px gray; line-height: 5px;">
    <img src="x.gif" style="border:solid 0px gray;">
</a>
```

Lets say x.gif's dimensions are 5x5 px.  How can i make the hyperlink wrap tightly around x.gif?  Right now the width is right but there seems to be padding on top and bottom  of x.gif.

Comment: #babiker , is it due to border 1px you gave???

Comment: i think its happening due to border on href ,can you change it to div is possible

Comment: The `font-size` is determining the height of the `<a>` when the `<a>` has its default `display: inline;`. The `line-height` is, more or less, about the the spacing between lines rather than the actual rendered height of a line or inline element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<a href="#" style="border:solid 1px gray; display: inline-block;">
    <img src="x.gif" style="display: block;">
</a>
```

If you need to support IE7 then you'll probably have to replace the `inline-block` with `block` in an IE7-specific stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin:0; padding:0; to your image.

Answer (score 0):

This is MSIE specific behaviour. It's sensitive to whitespace around the `<img>` tag as well.

To fix it, you could just remove any whitespace around it:

```
<a href="#" style="border: solid 1px gray; line-height: 5px;"><img src="x.gif" style="border: 0;" width="5" height="5"></a>
```

Note that giving a zero-wide border a color and style doesn't make sense, so I removed it from the image's style as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me across the latest browsers I tested on including IE9

```
<a href="#" style="font-size:0;text-decoration:none;">
    <img src="x.png" style="border:1px red solid;">
</a>
```

However while it looked pretty close in IE6/7 they produced a weird artefact on the bottom let corner of the border. I had to mimic the look in IE6/7 by cheating the border with background-color and padding. I also had to give the A element ["layout"](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) using zoom:1 to get it to behave (and loose some extra padding).

```
<a href="#" style="font-size:0;text-decoration:none;background-color:red;padding:1px;zoom:1;">
    <img src="x.png" style="border:none">
</a>
```

Annoyingly this didn't work with the "Standards" browsers so you'd have to use [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) and target low versions of IE with their own styles if you can't live with the artefact.